# SpringBootTest , content() function has gone with sprint-test 5.2.6

Tags: spring-boot, spring-test

I'm trying to do something similar to:

```
mockMvc
  .perform(post("/forums/{forumId}/register", 42L)
  .contentType("application/json")       
  .param("sendWelcomeMail", "true")
  .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(user)))             
  .andExpect(status().isOk());
```

But the .content method has disappeared with 5.2.6, there is now what seems to be a body() function:

```
mockMvc
   .perform(post("/conversions/ktoc")
   .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)                    
   .body(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(request)). /*missing method to get back to Builder*/                
   .andExpect(status().isOk());
```

Can someone assist please, all the examples I find on web all point to using content(..) method

Answer (score 0):

There should be still the `.content()` method in Spring Test 5.2.6 according to the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/request/MockMvcRequestBuilders.html).

What might have happened to your code is that your import the reactive version of `MockMvcRequestBuilders` from `org.springframework.mock.http.server.reactive.MockServerHttpRequest.post` and this has indeed no `.content()` method but only `.body()`.

So insure that your import the servlet version inside your test:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;

import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.post;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

@WebMvcTest
class PublicControllerTest {

  @Autowired
  private MockMvc mockMvc;

  @Test
  public void testMe() throws Exception {
    this.mockMvc
      .perform(post("/test").content("Some content"))
      .andExpect(status().isOk());
  }

}
```